# Could an Alcubierre Drive modify a gravitational field?

Tags: gravitational-waves, warp-drives

I'm a high school student, so I have no clue if warping spacetime has any effect on gravitational fields, but the two seemed to be linked based on what I've watched and read. And if a warp drive is possible (not nessecarily for ftl travel) could it be used for artificial or antigravity applications?

Comment: You might want to read this on the Alcubierre drive as it's more of an attempt to explain without math, where-as the Wikipedia version has lots of equations. http://www.askamathematician.com/2013/02/q-is-the-alcubierre-warp-drive-really-possible-how-close-are-we-to-actually-building-one-and-going-faster-than-light/    Alcubeirre drives may well not be possible so saying anything definitive about them is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just randomly warp spacetime. The curvature of spacetime is related to the matter that is present. It's a bit more complicated than that because it's actually related to an object called the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), but in most cases that just means the amount of matter present. Anyhow, the curvature of spacetime is what we call gravity.

The Earth warps spacetime in it's vicinity by having about $6 \times 10^{24}$ kg of (normal) matter in a ball. An Alcubierre drive warps spacetime by having a ring of [exotic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter) (views differ on the amount of exotic matter needed). In both cases the matter that is present curves spacetime and produces a gravitational field - the difference is in the shape of the matter and its type. For the record, as far as we know exotic matter doesn't exist, and if it did it would cause all sorts of problems with the stability of the universe.

So your question is really something along the lines of *could exotic matter, as used by the Alcubierre drive, be used for artificial or antigravity applications?*. And the answer is yes it could. If exotic matter existed and could be easily handled the physicists would be happier than a child in a toy shop. Sadly for the physicists, but luckily for the universe, exotic matter (probably) doesn't exist.